# iOS: Simulator crashes on trying to load SVG files?

Tags: swift, uicolor

I wanted to have some custom icons for my app, so I downloaded them from Icons8, in SVG Format. For reference, here is one the icons that I [downloaded.](https://icons8.com/icon/itk0HgSmVosD/sheep)

When I try to show these icons in a collection view, the app immediately crashes, giving me this error:

```
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Crashing on this line in the file UIColor+Extensions.swift, implying that the colours are too high a value, but when I am trying to read up on how this happens, I can't find any info on it. I am new to programming so apologies if this problem is a bit daft, but why does this problem occur? Is it really that the colours have too high rgb values?

```
self.init(red: colorsArray[0] / 255.0, green: colorsArray[1] / 255.0, blue: colorsArray[2] / 255.0, alpha: (colorsArray.count > 3 ? colorsArray[3] / 1.0 : 1.0))
```

For reference, I loaded them through using the SwiftSVG Pod like so:

```
func loadActivityIcons() {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
    let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path) 

    for item in items {
        if item.hasPrefix("icon") {
            if let item = item.components(separatedBy: ".").first {
                icons.append(item)
            }
       }
```

And then:

```
let icon = UIView(SVGNamed: icons[indexPath.row])
    cell.icon.addSubview(icon)
```

Comment: On what line does the crash happen? The error is about accessing an array and not about RGB values.

Comment: The `colorsArray` there has less than three elements. Could be caused by an issue with one of your SVG files - try to identify if its a specific file you’re trying to display.